# Chisel Output with SystemVerilog Interfaces/Structs

Tags: chisel

I'm finding when generating Verilog output from the Chisel framework, all of the 'structure' defined in the chisel framework is lost at the interface.

This is problematic for instantiating this work in larger SystemVerilog designs.

Are there any extensions or features in Chisel to support this better? For example, automatically converting Chisel "Bundle" objects into SystemVerilog 'struct' ports.

Or creating SV enums, when the Chisel code is written using the Enum class.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, no. However, both suggestions sound like very good candidates for discussion for future implementation in Chisel/FIRRTL.

### SystemVerilog Struct Generation

Most Chisel code instantiated inside Verilog/SystemVerilog will use some interface wrapper that deals with converting the necessary signal names that the instantiator wants to use into Chisel-friendly names. As one example of doing this see [`AcceleratorWrapper`](https://github.com/IBM/esp-chisel-accelerators/blob/e7e2467467264ce5933d7164dd6c1dbb1f5e5077/src/main/scala/esp/AcceleratorWrapper.scala#L66). That instantiates a specific accelerator and does the connections to the Verilog names the instantiator expects. You can't currently do this with SystemVerilog structs, but you could accomplish the same thing with a SystemVerilog wrapper that maps the SystemVerilog structs to deterministic Chisel names. This is the same type of problem/solution that most people encounter/solve when integrating external IP in their project.

Kludges aside, what you're talking about is possible in the future...

Some explanation is necessary as to why this is complex:

Chisel is converted to FIRRTL. FIRRTL is then lowered to a reduced subset of FIRRTL called "low" FIRRTL. Low FIRRTL is then mapped to Verilog. Part of this lowering process flattens all bundles using uniquely determined names (typically `a.b.c` will lower to `a_b_c` but will be uniquified if a namespace conflict due to the lowering would result). Verilog has no support for structs, so this has to happen. Additionally, and more critically, some optimizations happen at the Low FIRRTL level like Constant Propagation and Dead Code Elimination that are easier to write and handle there.

However, SystemVerilog or some other language that a FIRRTL backend is targeting that supports non-flat types benefits from using the features of that language to produce more human-readable output. There are two general approaches for rectifying this:

1. Lowered types retain information about how they were originally constructed via annotations and the SystemVerilog emitter reconstructs those. This seems inelegant due to lowering and then un-lowering.
2. The SystemVerilog emitter uses a different sequence of FIRRTL transforms that does not go all the way to Low FIRRTL. This would require some of the optimizing transforms run on Low FIRRTL to be rewritten to work on higher forms. This is tractable, but hard.

If you want some more information on what passes are run during each compiler phase, take a look at [`LoweringCompilers.scala`](https://github.com/freechipsproject/firrtl/blob/master/src/main/scala/firrtl/LoweringCompilers.scala)

### Enumerated Types

What you mention for `Enum` is planned for the Verilog backend. The idea here was to have `Enum`s emit annotations describing what they are. The Verilog emitter would then generate `localparam`s. The preliminary work for annotation generation was added as part of `StrongEnum` ([`chisel3#885`](https://github.com/freechipsproject/chisel3/issues/885)/[`chisel3#892`](https://github.com/freechipsproject/chisel3/pull/892)), but the annotations portion had to be later backed out. A solution to this is actively being worked on. A subsequent PR to FIRRTL will then augment the Verilog emitter to use these. So, look for this going forward.

### On Contributions and Outreach

For questions like this with (currently) negative answers, feel free to file an issue on the respective Chisel3 or FIRRTL repository. And even better than that is an RFC followed by an implementation.